# Connector Identification on Instrument

Tags: connector, serial, parallel, rs232

I have a piece of instrument made around 2000 with a connector to computer that I cannot recognize. Can someone help me out? It is a 20-pin connector, with 10 pins on each row. Pictures are here: https://photos.app.goo.gl/ZF6i9fdpoevncE5j8 
The connector in question is marked "Computer". I suspect it is some kind of scsi.

[image]

Apologize for not saying anything of the instrument. It is a Thermo-Nicolet Nexus 670 FT-IR Spectrophotometer, made in the USA. It was the work horse of the infrared spectroscopy community. It is not one of a find. I thought it is not too relevant, since "computers" that worth interface to in year 2000 are limited to IBM PC.

Comment: It would help to know what kind of instrument (to guess what data rate might be required) and who manufactured it (for example, are they an American, European, or Japanese company), etc.

Comment: The connector looks like a [3M MDR](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/d-shaped-connectors-centronics/438?k=&pkeyword=&sv=0&pv88=34&sf=0&FV=ffec300b&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=25) style. But it's not a standard PC interface I recognize.

Comment: Yes, could be SCSI:  http://www.starte-e.net/product/scsi-hpcn-20-pin-female-connector/

Comment: downvote .... it makes absolutely sense to post a question that asks to identify the purpose of a connector and say absolutely nothing about the device that it is part of

Comment: It looks like a proprietary interface.

Comment: I know some of these machines were connected to Dell computers.

Answer (score 1):

Look at D-Shaped Centronics connectors. Similar to this one from 3M 
[3M1816-ND](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/3m/10220-6212PC/3M1816-ND/1091779) on Digi-Key's site.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it is indeed a proprietary interface. The instrument requires a separate card on the PC expansion slot for data processing. Thank you all for your kind help. The task now is either to find one of those card or find a way to sniff the signals on the pins and decode them. Maybe then we can use today's software to replicate 20 year old hardware functions.